# Swift SpriteKit 接触処理（didBegin） が動作しない

Tags: swift, xcode, spritekit

didBegin内に1つのNodeに対する接触は問題なく動作するのですが、didBegin内にもう一つ別のNodeの接触処理を書いたとこと、うまく作動しません。
どうかよろしくお願い致します。

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var asteroid: SKPhysicsBody
    var target: SKPhysicsBody
    var itemBox: SKPhysicsBody

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == asteroidCategory {
        asteroid = contact.bodyA
        target = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        asteroid = contact.bodyB
        target = contact.bodyA
    }

    // ** 別の接触処置を記す場合、このコードでbodyAとbodyBを宣言してはダメなのでしょうか。
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == itemBoxCategory {
        itemBox = contact.bodyA
        target = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        itemBox = contact.bodyB
        target = contact.bodyA
    }

    guard let asteroidNode = asteroid.node as? AsteroidNode else { return }
    guard let tagetNode = target.node else { return }
    guard let itemBoxNode = itemBox.node else { return }

    // ** ここが作動しません。
    if(contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == itemBoxCategory && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == spaceshipCategory)  || (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == itemBoxCategory && contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == spaceshipCategory) {
        itemBoxNode.removeFromParent()
        addChild(item1)
    }

    guard let Bakuhatu = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Bakuhatu") else { return }
    Bakuhatu.position = asteroidNode.position
    addChild(Bakuhatu)

    if target.categoryBitMask == missileCategory  {
        tagetNode.removeFromParent()
        asteroidNode.life -= missile.Pw

        if asteroidNode.life <= 0 {
            asteroidNode.removeFromParent()
        }
    }

    self.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0)) {
        Bakuhatu.removeFromParent()
    }

    if target.categoryBitMask == spaceshipCategory {
        asteroidNode.removeFromParent()
        self.gameVC.lifeGauge.setProgress(gameVC.lifeGauge.progress - 0.2, animated: true)
        lifeLabel.text = "Life:\(Int(gameVC.lifeGauge.progress * 100))"

        if self.gameVC.lifeGauge.progress <= 0.0 {
            GameOver()
        }
    }

}
```

※補足
接触に必要な
categoryBitMask
collisionBitMask
contactTestBitMask
は、下記の様に設定しております。

```
let spaceshipCategory : UInt32 = 0b0001
let missileCategory : UInt32 = 0b0010
let asteroidCategory  : UInt32 = 0b0100
let itemBoxCategory : UInt32 = 0b1000

//spaceship
self.spaceship.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = spaceshipCategory
self.spaceship.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = spaceshipCategory | missileCategory | asteroidCategory | itemBoxCategory
self.spaceship.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = asteroidCategory

//itemBox
itemBox.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = itemBoxCategory
itemBox.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = spaceshipCategory | itemBoxCategory
itemBox.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = spaceshipCategory
```

Comment: itemBoxとspaceshipとの間の接触判定ができるような、正しい`contactTestBitMask`の設定はできていますか？

Comment: @OOPer さん
ご確認ありがとうございます。
質問本文に現在のitemBoxとspaceshipの設定を記載いたしました。
接触に関しては問題ないと思っておりましたが、ミスがございましたらご指摘頂けると幸いです。

Comment: 情報の追記ありがとうございます。`self.spaceship.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = asteroidCategory`とありますから、これではspaceshipと接触判定できるのは相手が、asteroidの場合だけと言うことになりますね。itemBox側でspaceshipとの衝突判定を記述したので、大丈夫だと思われたかもしれませんが、これではうまく検出できない時があります。

Comment: @OOPer さん
ご回答ありがとうございます！
早速修正して試してみましたが、やはり下記コードのitemBoxとspaceshipの接触によるアクションが行われません。
didBegin内のif分や接触のコードに大きな間違いは特に見当たらないでしょうか？
何卒よろしくお願い致します。
if(contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == itemBoxCategory && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == spaceshipCategory)  || (contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == itemBoxCategory && contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == spaceshipCategory) {
                itemBoxNode.removeFromParent()
                addChild(item1)
            }

Comment: 修正と確認ありがとうございます。`didBegin`の処理には大いに問題がありそう(asteroi対何か、しか扱えないコードに無理に処理を足している)ですが、今はちょっと時間が取れません。後で時間が取れたときに回答の形で示させていただきます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず大前提ですが、「spaceshipとitemBoxの接触を検出したい」と言う場合には、コメントに示したように、spaceship側とitemBox側の両方の`contactTestBitMask`に相手側を指定するようにしてください。片側だけだと、うまく検出してくれない場合があるようです。

```
self.spaceship.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = asteroidCategory | itemBoxCategory
```

---

さて、その部分の設定は正しくできているとして、あなたの現在の`didBegin(_:)`を見てみると、最も問題になるのはこの行だと言えます。

```
    guard let asteroidNode = asteroid.node as? AsteroidNode else { return }
```

この行、「asteroid対何か」「何か対asteroid」の接触時の処理を書くためには必須のものですが、それ以外の接触でこの行にたどり着いた場合、変数`asteroid`には、その名前に反してasteroidを表す`SKPhysicsBody`は入っていませんから、`as? AsteroidNode`の結果が必ず`nil`となり、else節内の`return`で処理を終了してしまいます。

---

今までは「asteroid対何か」「何か対asteroid」でしか`didBegin(_:)`が呼ばれなかったところに「itemBox対spaceship」「spaceship対itemBox」の処理を割り込ませたために、どの部分がどんな場合に実行されるのかと言ったことがごっちゃになってしまっているのが、ある場合には必要な行が別の場合に邪魔をする、と言う原因になっています。

混乱を避けるためには、接触時の処理の種類ごとにメソッドを分けてやると良いでしょう。

```
//「asteroid対何か」「何か対asteroid」
    func hit(asteroid: SKPhysicsBody, target: SKPhysicsBody) {

        guard let asteroidNode = asteroid.node as? AsteroidNode else { return }
        guard let tagetNode = target.node else { return }

        guard let bakuhatu = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Bakuhatu") else { return }
        bakuhatu.position = asteroidNode.position
        addChild(bakuhatu)

        if target.categoryBitMask == missileCategory  {
            tagetNode.removeFromParent()
            asteroidNode.life -= missile.Pw

            if asteroidNode.life <= 0 {
                asteroidNode.removeFromParent()
            }
        }

        self.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0)) {
            bakuhatu.removeFromParent()
        }

        if target.categoryBitMask == spaceshipCategory {
            asteroidNode.removeFromParent()
            self.gameVC.lifeGauge.setProgress(gameVC.lifeGauge.progress - 0.2, animated: true)
            lifeLabel.text = "Life:\(Int(gameVC.lifeGauge.progress * 100))"

            if self.gameVC.lifeGauge.progress <= 0.0 {
                GameOver()
            }
        }

    }

    //「itemBox対spaceship」「spaceship対itemBox」
    func hit(itemBox: SKPhysicsBody, target: SKPhysicsBody) {

        guard let itemBoxNode = itemBox.node else { return }

        itemBoxNode.removeFromParent()
        addChild(item1)

        //...
    }
```

(`hit(asteroid:target:)`中に書かれた処理の一部は、`hit(itemBox:target:)`にも必要なのかもしれません。その場合は、`//...`のところの必要な処理を追加していってください。もちろん両者に共通な処理は、さらに別のメソッドを作って、そこにまとめてしまっても構いません。)

---

上記のようなメソッドを用意した上で、`didBegin(_:)`の中では、接触の種類に応じて、上記のメソッドを呼び出してやるだけ、と言った具合にします。

ただし、

```
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == asteroidCategory {
        //...
    } else {
        //...
    }
```

と言った簡易判定は、接触判定の種類が「asteroid対何か」「何か対asteroid」しかなかったからうまくいっていたものです。接触判定の種類が増えた場合、簡易判定を2箇所に別個に書いても正しい判定はできません。

現在は、処理を行いたい接触は「asteroid対何か」「何か対asteroid」「itemBox対spaceship」「spaceship対itemBox」の4通りですから、それらをきちんと判定してやらないといけません。

```
    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == asteroidCategory {
            //「asteroid対何か」
            hit(asteroid: contact.bodyA, target: contact.bodyB)
        } else if contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == asteroidCategory {
            //「何か対asteroid」
            hit(asteroid: contact.bodyB, target: contact.bodyA)
        } else if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == itemBoxCategory && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == spaceshipCategory {
            //「itemBox対spaceship」
            hit(itemBox: contact.bodyA, target: contact.bodyB)
        } else if contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == itemBoxCategory && contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == spaceshipCategory {
            //「spaceship対itemBox」
            hit(itemBox: contact.bodyB, target: contact.bodyA)
        }
    }
```

後は、接触判定の種類がもっと増えても、同じように「メソッドを増やす」「`didBegin(_:)`中の判定を増やす」で対応できるのはおわかりいただけると思います。

細かいところで修正が必要になるかもしれませんが、まずはお試しください。

Comment: @OOPerさん
非常に丁寧なご質問、心より感謝致します。
初心者にもご説明がわかりやすく記載頂いており、かつ私の知りたい的確な内容でした。いつもありがとうございます。
また、今後も円滑にプログラミングができる様な再現性のあるご回答内容であったと感じております。

OOPerさんにご回答頂きました内容でコードを編集致しました。
お陰様で、問題なくasteroidとmissile、itemBoxとspaceshipの接触はできました。
しかし、asteroidとspaceshipの接触後のメソッドのみ呼び出されませんでした。

Comment: 恐らくですが、同メソッド内「asteroidとmissile」の接触は上手くいっているので、下記のコードに問題があるのかと思われます。
   ` if target.categoryBitMask == missileCategory {
        tagetNode.removeFromParent()
        asteroidNode.life -= missile.Pw

        if asteroidNode.life <= 0 {
            asteroidNode.removeFromParent()
        }
    }
    self.run(SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0)) {
        bakuhatu.removeFromParent()
    }
    if target.contactTestBitMask == spaceshipCategory {
        asteroidNode.removeFromParent()
        life -= 100
        if life <= 0 {
            GameOver()
      }
    }`

Comment: また、itemBoxとasteroidの接触とメソッドが終了後、再度itemBoxとasteroidの接触とメソッドが行われるとエラーが発生しクラッシュします。
現在こちら改善に向けて取り組んでおりますが、もし原因がお分かりになる様でしたらご教授頂けますと幸いでございます。
「エラーコード」Thread 1: Exception: "Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: <SKSpriteNode> name:'item1' texture:[<SKTexture> 'item1' (1252 x 1300)] position:{-225, -517} scale:{1.00, 1.00} size:{100, 100} anchor:{0.5, 0.5} rotation:0.00"

Comment: コメントが見易くなく、大変申し訳ございません。
今後より見易いコメントを残せる様、コメントの残し方を学習いたします。

Comment: @sho さん、動作確認ありがとうございます。「asteroidとspaceshipの接触後のメソッドのみ呼び出されませんでした」とありますが、「asteroidとspaceshipの接触の場合、`hit(asteroid:target:)`メソッドが呼び出されない」のか、「asteroidとspaceshipの接触の場合、`hit(asteroid:target:)`メソッドは呼び出されているが、asteroidとspaceshipの接触処理の部分が実行されていない」のか、それとも「asteroidとspaceshipの接触の場合、`hit(asteroid:target:)`メソッドは呼び出されており、asteroidとspaceshipの接触処理の部分も実行されているが、期待通りの動作にならない」のか、どれでしょうか?

Comment: @OOPerさん、早速のご確認ありがとうございます。　現状、asteroidとspaceshipの接触時にメソッド内の    addChild(bakuhatu)が動作している為、恐らく頂いた内容の２番目にあたり、hit(asteroid:target:)　のメソッドは呼び出されているが、asteroidとspaceshipの接触処理の部分が実行されていない」と思われます。

Comment: @sho さん、「恐らく」では確実に何が起こっているか判断するのは難しいです。例えば`if target.categoryBitMask == spaceshipCategory {`の行の後に`print("target=spaceship")`という行を置くと、デバッグコンソールには`target=spaceship`が表示されるでしょうか?

Comment: @OOPerさん、承知いたしました。本日中に確認し、ご報告させて頂きます。

Comment: @OOPerさん、大変申し訳ございます。メソッドの呼び出しが上手くいかなかったのは私のコードに凡ミスがございました、（categoryBitMask→contactTestBitMask）お恥ずかしい限りです。
OOPerさんにご回答いただきましたコードで上手く作動致しました。
問題が完璧に解決されました。本当にありがとうございます。

Comment: @sho さん、ご報告ありがとうございます。何かのミスが入りうると言うのはどんな回答でも起こることなので、多少のミスは気になさらずに、うまくいかない場合にはご報告いただけると助かります。

Comment: @OOPerさん、
アドバイスありがとうございます。
今回も的確なご回答頂きまして本当にありがとうございます。
いつも本当に感謝しております。